# Javascript style assignment only works in Opera (but not in Firefox or IE8)

Tags: javascript, html

**The following javascript code works perfectly in Opera(v10.5x), but fails miserably in Firefox(v3.6) and IE8.**

```
function HighlightBox(elementid,highlight)
{
      var hstyle="none";

      if (highlight)
        {        
        switch (elementid) 
        {
              case 'emailbox':
              case 'lastnamebox':
              case 'firstnamebox':
              case 'campusbox':                         
                hstyle="width:275px;height:70px;border:2px solid red;";                                                         
                break;
              case 'isdbox':
                hstyle="width:275px;height:100px;border:2px solid red;";
                break;
        }
        }

    document.getElementById(elementid).style = hstyle;  
}
```

**I have tried individual assignments like:**

```
document.getElementById(elementid).style.width="275px";
...
```

**But these don't seem to work either.**

*I appreciate any assistance in this matter.
Thank you,
Ai Pragma*

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browser?

Comment: Also, please ensure the function is called during page load. You have to call the function in the window.onload event. Otherwise you will get the "document.getElementById(elementid)" is null error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that purpose you can try to use the `cssText` property, is [widely supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#properties):

```
document.getElementById(elementid).style.cssText = "width:275px;height:100px;border:2px solid red;"
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/ahisi4/).

Comment: Well CMS, your suggestion to use .cssText worked well, in all browsers. I am using Aptana(v2.0.4) IDE as my javascript & HTML editor, and I had tried several combinations from Aptana's 'autocompletion' dropdown list for '.style.' , and after reading your suggestion, I went back to Aptana to see of I had missed that combination, and Aptana does not list 'cssText' in its dropdown list. I was very surprised by this. Anyway, thank you again for your suggestion, it works very well.  
Ai Pragma

Comment: @AiPragma: The `cssText` property is part of the [DOM Level 2 Style Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html) (is a member of the `CSSRule` interface), it's strange that Aptana doesn't list this property... Anyway welcome to SO, I'm glad to help, remember that you can mark the best answer to your questions as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), give a look to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) :-)